# How can I use puppeteer for react-native?

Tags: android, react-native, testing, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I want to run e2e automation testing for the app I developed using react-native using puppeteer. May I know how can I do that?

Comment: You might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55049611/5627599).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it. Puppeteer will work only for webview. React native is not made of webview.

You can use detox to do e2e testing in react native. Checkout some articles if you are a newbie. Check out....

https://medium.com/@reime005/react-native-end-to-end-testing-d488e010e39f