# Is it possible to run Puppeteer on server-side?

Tags: node.js, websocket, puppeteer, remote-debugging, webautomation

I want to use Puppeteer to automate a particular task. However, for user-friendly purposes, I thought about implementing it within a chrome extension. Browsing the web, I encountered this article https://dev.to/tchan/web-automation-using-puppeteer-inside-a-chrome-extension-318o To be honest, I could not absorb some context from the article since I don't have enough experience about that kind of stuff. According to the article, I had to activate **remote debugging** for chrome. So I did, yet could not access localhost, thus **webSocketDebuggerUrl** property, either. Some connection refusal error hit on the browser while trying to access. But the thing about I care is that in the case that it even works, if I had published this extension, one would have to activate his/her remote debugging for chrome, too and that would not be much of user-friendly. In the end, I thought that if it is possible to run Puppeteer on nodejs with your own computer, it should be possible to run it on server-side(nodejs) of a website, too. Thus, you wouldn't need an extension, so the website itself would implement the task I have intended. 
Sorry for this long story-wise problem, but still I don't have much knowledge of server-side languages. So is it possible to run Puppeteer on server-side? So what would you recommend to do? 
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @jarvissa, actually it is much rare (if even possible to do it properly) to run puppeteer on the client side. Puppeteer normally should be run on the server side and in Node.js environment. Maybe if you "reverse" your question and you look for "puppeteer on the client side" questions on Stackoverflow then you will find lots of useful answers. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031823/how-to-make-puppeteer-work-with-a-reactjs-application-on-the-client-side