# Use puppeteer with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, puppeteer

How can I use puppeteer with webpack? No matter what I try it cannot find it. Here's as far as I got:

Dependency is installed in package.json:

```
npm i puppeteer
```

In webpack.dev:

```
module.exports = {
    // ... I'm skipping over a bunch of stuff here, then:
    externals: {
        puppeteer: require('puppeteer'),
    }
}\\
```

Then in my entry file index.js on the client side:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
```

Immediately after I run:

```
puppeteer.launch();
```

Only to get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'launch' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm always struggling with using external plugins within webpack.

Quick update, I tried the webpack.providePlugin and tested it with the jquery library in parallel. The jquery works by following the same logic, but puppeteer still gives me an error:

In webpack.dev:

```
    plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        puppeteer: 'puppeteer',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
```

in index.js:

```
import 'puppeteer'
import 'jquery'
```

Then I get a bunch of errors such as:

```
/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\victo\OneDrive\Desktop\20200307-kino\kino\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node'
errors @ client:159
eval @ socket.js:47
sock.onmessage @ SockJSClient.js:67
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
eval @ sockjs.js:888
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:886
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2962
client:159 ./node_modules/extract-zip/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\victo\OneDrive\Desktop\20200307-kino\kino\node_modules\extract-zip'
```

Comment: Why would you need `externals`?

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Puppeteer work with a ReactJS application on the client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031823/how-to-make-puppeteer-work-with-a-reactjs-application-on-the-client-side)

Answer (score 2):

I did encounter similar issues while using webpack for node application with puppeteer as a dependency. In your case simple:

```
module.exports = {
    // other conf
    externals: {
        puppeteer: "require('puppeteer')", // use additional double quotes here to define valid external
    }
}
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your config as follows. that worked for in my case. The commented out ones might apply as well

```
module.exports = {
// ... 
node: {
  child_process: 'empty',
  // net: 'empty',
  // dns: 'empty',
  // tls: 'empty',
  // readline: 'empty'
}
}
```