# How to take a screenost of rendered html to create a png?

Tags: node.js, image, screenshot, headless-browser

I need to dynamically generate images containing a persons photo and various bits of 'status' information.  I have some designs from our designer.

Looking at the designs the easiest way (for me) would be to generate that look using the tools I know - HTML, CSS, ReactJs etc.

But how can I essentially 'take a screenshot' (on the server) of what the browser would see and then save that out to a PNG?

Ideally I'd like to do this in nodejs but happy to consider c# or java or other languages if need be.

I know that nodejs will let you run a 'headless browser' for testing but what I want to do is essentially 'take a visual snapshot' of what those browsers 'see' and save to a png?

Keen to write this and run it on our server so looking for suggestions involving how I could code this up rather than an external service, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sending the views from Node.js server or running the front end on different server/FWs like angular, react? Do you need for the testing reporting or from the acutal website?

Comment: Hey thanks for the question.. uhm it's a little bit snake eating its own tail I guess. What I had in mind was image_url -> nodejs route (check.cache) -> headless browser -> reactjs frontend (hosted by same nodejs)

Comment: Still looking into this but this looks relevant 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031823/how-to-make-puppeteer-work-with-a-reactjs-application-on-the-client-side